# Are there any error functions with imbalanced negative/positive impact

Tags: python, scikit-learn, optimization, cost-function

I have a regression task, where positive error should be much worse than negative one. It means the importance of **positive error** bigger. For example, If real value is **less** than predicted one weights will change normally. But if real value **bigger** than predicted weights should change 10x times.

I'm not ready to make the whole algorithm from scratch, so there are must be ways or **regression algorithms** with that type of functionality in scikit-learn for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is possible to amplify positive values and the regression should work fine.

For instance, if value > 0, just multiply value by 10 (or more).

In some cases, applying a power could be better, which means if value > 0, then value^x, with x>1.0.

Note: Fine-tuning x could be interesting because it doesn't have to be an integer. It could be something like 1.5 or 2.3. This solution is very useful to amplify values in a non-linear way (the higher the value = the much worse the error is).

Conversely, you can also lower negative values error with x<1 in a non-linear way.

Comment: Here i have problem with Loss function, which i can't edit or simply create (for scikit-learn package, as i know). I need to fit a model by punishing severely for positive error, or if (y-y~) >0. The thing i'm interested in is if there any ways to implement this (some weights i can tune(in packages i don't know) or special Loss functions that allow me work in that way, or even different regression models, which allows it)

Comment: You don't have to modify the model, you just have to create data that fits your needs. Sometimes, adapted data is better than adapted models.